# VB.NET localization

Tags: vb.net, localization

In my winform app in VB.NET I want to use the localization option.

But i have a few questions/problems.

I'm using a menu strip to select an other language.
But it seems that is doesn't change my menustip text to my selected language. It does change my labels, buttons, and textboxes but menu strips don't seem to change when I choose another language.

Also is it possible to get those resx files such as MyForm.fr-FR.resx compiled so it isn't an external file outside my app? Or to get those files in an Language folder at the same location of my app, so i don't have all those fr-FR & nl-Nl folders in the same location as my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_localize_at_runtime.html

Got it solved with this example.